# Why does emacs put a black background on comments?

Tags: colors, comment

For some reason emacs shows comments on a black background. The image shows an example from my emacs with the otherwise amazing color theme "aalto-dark" from the color-theme-modern package. I don't like how the comments look. Is the black background a part of the color theme, or is it some other configuration in my .emacs file that creates this? How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Why not move to the more modern deftheme collection [here](https://github.com/emacs-jp/replace-colorthemes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my computer and it disappeared. Restarting emacs did not help. I am using Ubuntu 17.10. I have no idea why the restart worked.
[image]

Comment: It's not just the black background. The text was changed to italic also, and the foreground color was changed to red. Sounds like you somehow changed the face used for comments in that session (without saving that change). But restarting Emacs should have taken care of that...